# Bringing matrices to the other side of the equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say that A, B, and C are all 2x2 matrices such that AC = B; if I want to multiply both sides by the inverse of A to "bring" A to the other side of the equation, would it be C = B$A^{-1}$ or C = $A^{-1}$B? Is there a general rule for multiplying both sides of the equation with an element and where the element should be placed?

Comment: Left-multiply by $A^{-1}$, since $A^{-1}A=I$

Comment: Matrix multiplication is not commutative. This means that, generally, $A^{-1}B \ne BA^{-1}$. To undo multiplication by a matrix, you must multiply the product by the inverse of said matrix (if it exists) in the same direction as the original matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is that if you multiply by $A^{-1}$ on the left/right of a term, you must also multiply on the left/right on the other side of the equation. In your case, if $AC= B$ then, $A^{-1} (A C) = A^{-1} B$. Hence by associativity, $(A^{-1} A)C = IC= C = A^{-1} B$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. This is assuming, of course, that multiplication by $A$ is defined.